Application of Picard-Lindelof Theorem to enumerate all solutions of $y'=y^2.$
How to use Picard-Lindelof Theorem to show that all solutions of $y'=y^2$ on some open interval $I$ bounded in one-side are either of the form $y=\frac{1}{-x+C}$ (where $C$ is any constant that is not in $I$) or $y=0$? And if the interval is the whole real line then the only solution is $y=0$?
What I mean by a solution on an open interval $I$ is a function $\phi:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable everywhere on $I$ and for every $x\in I$, $\phi'(x)=\phi(x)^2$
Even though $y'=y^2$ is a simple ODE that can be solved by separation of variables, I'm still troubled to find a way to rigorously enumerate all solutions (on a given interval).

It is not clear what you are asking. A solution can blow up inside an interval. What exactly do you mean by a solution?

@copper.hat, a solution on an open interval I is a function $y(x)$ whose domain is $I$ and for every $x$ in $I$, $y'(x)=y(x)^2$

So, you are assuming that $y$ is finite for all $x\in I$?

yeah, I mean the domain is $I$ so obviously $y(x)$ is finite for every $x\in I$

And is the interval bounded? Is that obvious too?

the interval may not be bounded

I don't really want to keep chatting about this, just note that the choice of interval has a significant impact on the allowable solutions. For example, if $I$ is the real line then there is exactly one solution as you have obviously defined it above.

By solving the ODE you found the solutions
\begin{align}\tag1
y&\equiv 0\,,&\text{ which exists  on }I=\mathbb R\,,\\[2mm]
y&=\frac 1{-x+C}\,,&\text{ which exists  on }\mathbb R\setminus C\,.\tag2
\end{align}
Obviously, the first solution only satisfies the IVP when the initial condition is $y(0)=0\,.$ The second solution satisfies every initial condition $y(0)\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ for a suitable $C\,.$
The Picard-Lindelöf theorem to this ODE is applicable since the function $y^2$ is locally Lipschitz on $\mathbb R$ (but not globally Lipschitz). This means that
for every initial condition there is a unique solution not necessarily defined on all of $\mathbb R\,.$
Conclusion? Should be clear: there are no other solutions other than (1) and (2).
